# How to prevent modal boxes for Drupal 7 edit forms

Tags: forms

I am very annoyed by the modal boxes showing up for most edit functions in Drupal. For example, when editing a php field code, only a few lines are displayed, I must copy the content in an other editor and back.
How can we prevent this "smart" feature to get back to the old fashion editing?

Comment: Uninstall the overlay module. https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/administering-drupal-7-site/working-with-the-overlay#s-disabling

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but this does not seem to be related to the Overlay module - it was already disabled and after uninstalling it, the modal boxes keep showing. As I cannot upload a screenshot, here is the main div of this box : <div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all views-ui-dialog ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-views-ajax-popup" style="display: none;z-index: 1002;outline: 0px;height: 475px;width: 1141px;top: 59.5px;left: 381px;">